# Parse XML time series data to dat files

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

i'm trying to parse an XML with time series data to individual .dat files for each location. So far I can extract the time series data, but I can't get the location ID out, and as a header to the relevant time series data. Tried several methods found on SO, but nothing yet. Would appreciate any help possible, or pointers.

Sample input XML:

```
<TimeSeries>
    <timeZone>0.0</timeZone>
    <series>
        <header>
            <type>mean</type>
            <locationId>abc</locationId>
            <parameterId>xxx</parameterId>
            <units>x</units>
        </header>
        <event date="2015-06-24" time="06:45:00" value="0.0"/>
        <event date="2015-06-24" time="06:50:00" value="0.0"/>
    </series>
    <series>
        <header>
            <type>mean</type>
            <locationId>def</locationId>
            <parameterId>yyy</parameterId>
            <units>x</units>
        </header>
        <event date="2015-06-24" time="06:45:00" value="0.0"/>
        <event date="2015-06-24" time="06:50:00" value="0.0"/>
    </series>
</TimeSeries>
```

Code so far (the middle part with the location is not working, but the bottom half pulls out the time series data nicely)

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

with open('foo.xml', 'rt') as document:
    tree = ElementTree.parse(document)

for location in tree.findall('series/header'):
    locationId = location.find('./locationId')
    print locationId.text

for node in tree.iter():
    date = node.attrib.get('date')
    time = node.attrib.get('time')
    value = node.attrib.get('value')
    if date and time:
        print '  %s , %s , %s' % (date, time, value)
```

Desired outcome:

```
abc
2015-06-24 , 06:45:00 , 0.0
2015-06-24 , 06:50:00 , 0.0

def
2015-06-24 , 06:45:00 , 0.0
2015-06-24 , 06:50:00 , 0.0
```

I know I need to eventually create a loop, so get the header first, then get the data, and so forth. In the end I will split the desired outcome into separate .dat file for each locationId.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should combine the two different `for` loops into a single one and use `xpaths` to find the elements you need. Example -

```
with open('foo.xml', 'rt') as document:
    tree = ElementTree.parse(document)
    for series in tree.findall('.//series'):
        locationId = series.find('./header/locationId').text
        print locationId
        events = series.findall('./event')
        for event in events:
            print '{}, {}, {}'.format(event.attrib.get('date'), event.attrib.get('time'), event.attrib.get('value'))
```

This first gets all the `series` elements. Then for each `series` element, it gets its corresponding `locationId` using the xpath - `./header/locationId` , and its corresponding `event` elements using xpath - `./event` .

Comment: many thanks for the help. It works perfectly with the test data, but now I'm struggling to adapt to my real data. If you don't mind (or I could ask a new question), it appears the name space (there is one in the Timeseries top line): <TimeSeries xmlns="http://www.xxxaaabbb/PI"> If I take this out it works fine, else it doesn't print. There is no error shown however...strange..

Comment: Try adding the namespace in the xpath , try - '//{<namespace>}series' . Etc

Comment: It doesn't seem to work...I'm trying to remove the name spaces now, see if that works...